# Convergence for $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-\cos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}))$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

The problem sounds as:

> Determine whether $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-\cos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}))$ converges or not

So, here's my argument. We can form the Taylor Series for $\cos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}})$. Let $T(x) = 1-\frac{1}{2k}+\frac{1}{24k^2} + \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{k^4})$

Then $1-\cos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}) = \frac{1}{2k} - \frac{1}{24k^2} + \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{k^4})$.

The new sum can be written as:

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2k} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{24k^2} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{k^4})$.

Because the first sum diverges, is it a valid argument to say that the original sum does so? Thanks!

Comment: What is $x$ in your argument? Your idea is sound. Another way is to note $$
1 - \cos \left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt k }}} \right) = 2\sin ^2 \left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt k }}} \right) \ge 2\left( {\frac{2}{\pi }\frac{1}{{\sqrt k }}} \right)^2  = \frac{8}{{\pi ^2 }} \cdot \frac{1}{k}
$$ since $\sin x>(2/\pi)x$ for $0<x<\pi/2$.

Comment: Since the seies is of nonnegative terms, I prefer to use comparison test, taking into account that $1-\cos(x)\sim\frac{x^2}{2}$ as $x\to0$.

Comment: @Gary Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Hint: the partial sums display logarithmic behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$1 - \cos \left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt k }}} \right) = 2\sin ^2 \left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt k }}} \right)$$

Now using Limit comparison test with $\frac{1}{k}$ we get

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{2\sin^{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)}{\frac{1}{k}}=2$$.

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}$ diverges . Hence By limit comparison test . The original series also diverges.

Answer (score 0):

The serie is definitely non-negative. We can use the asynpotic criteria:
$$1-\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)\sim \frac{1}{k}$$
Because we know the followinf notable limit:
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(t)}{t^2}=1$$
Now, we can apply the comparison test with $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ that diverges. Thus, your serie diverges.